# Can I use an environment variable to define an alias?

Tags: environment-variables, alias, bashrc

I'm using an automation engine to run perl scripts. script_X requires a wrapper script so it's run like:

```
wrapper_script script_X --parameters
```

But the automation engine can't understand that invocation. At the moment, I've manually edited ./bashrc to say:

```
alias script_X='wrapper_script script_X'
```

I'm currently testing to see if the automation engine will work with this. 
It can however handle environment variables.

Is it possible to export an environment variable to create/modify an alias?

(From comments, I realise this may be a convoluted method to solve a limitation, however I'm still interested in the answer to the original question, out of curiosity)

Comment: How does the "automation engine" understand enough to run script_X (in theory) but not a wrapper script? [what problem do you _really_ want to solve?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: it doesn't understand "wrapper script script_X". It understands wrapper_script and script_X but neither do what I want them to. I want to investigate if this is possible before I think about talking to the automation engine developers

Comment: can you define "script_XY" that is a simple script that's a double-wrapper -- it in turn calls wrapper_script with the necessary parameters? seems a really convoluted way to work around some sort of limitation.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing `wrapper_script` and probably `script_X` too.  What does `wrapper_script` do?  Why does `script_X` need it?  Is `script_X` executable (e.g. `chmod +x`).  Add this info to your question, not in a comment.

Comment: Wrapper_script is needed because of perl comparability issues. Whether it's a convoluted method or not - I'm still interested in whether it's possible to modify an alias with an env var

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to hashbang the **script_X** with the path of the right interpreter(wrapper_script).

```
#!/bin/wrapper_script 
(...blabla contents of script_X)
```

where /bin is of course, the right path to the wrapper_script. 
With that will just need to:

```
chmod +x script_X 
./script_X
```

This can solve your problem?